# Why is my unpickled sequence different than when it was pickled?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle

I got a little confused about the python variable persistence, in my code, I use the following code to make the model parameters persistent during some iterations

```
 with open('W_Hs_Hu_iter'+str(inx)+'.pickle', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump((self.W,self.Hs,self.Hu),f)
```

and after the long iteration, I try to load the model with

```
with open('W_Hs_Hu_iter450.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    W,Hs,Hu= pickle.load(f)
    #W,Hu,Hs= pickle.load(f)
```

but after I checked that, the sequence of Hs and Hu are wrong? can that happen?

Comment: Doesn't look wrong. What are the sequences before and after?

Comment: Yep. Just have tested it. Seems is ok. Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @peter-wood it looks correct, also I've tested it to make sure.

```
import pickle

class TestObj(object):
    def __init__(self, one=1, two=2, three=3):
        self.one = one
        self.two = two
        self.three = three

    def save(self):
        with open('D:\\test.pickle', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump((self.one,self.two,self.three),f,-1)

    @staticmethod
    def load():
        with open('D:\\test.pickle', 'rb') as f:
            one,two,three = pickle.load(f)
        test_obj = TestObj(one, two, three)
        return test_obj

test_obj = TestObj() #Init with defaults
test_obj.save()
print 'after save: one: %s, two: %s, three: %s' % (test_obj.one,test_obj.two,test_obj.three)
test_obj = test_obj.load()
print 'after load: one: %s, two: %s, three: %s' % (test_obj.one,test_obj.two,test_obj.three)
```

My best guess is that when you save, the values of `Hs` and `Hu` are already swapped around. Do a log\print before your save.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pickle of a class instance, where the attribute values are swapped after the pickling.

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...   a = 1
...   b = 2
...   def __init__(self, c,d):
...     self.c = c
...     self.d = d
...   def bar(self):
...     return self.a,self.b,self.c,self.d
... 
>>> f = Foo(3,4)
>>> _f = pickle.dumps(f)
>>> f.c,f.d = f.d,f.c
>>> f.b,f.a = f.a,f.b
>>> f_ = pickle.loads(_f)
>>> f_.bar()
(1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> f.bar()
(2, 1, 4, 3)
```

So, that works as expected.  However, python pickles classes by reference, so if you change the class definition, it will seemingly change the instance attributes.

```
>>> g = Foo(3,4)
>>> _g = pickle.dumps(g)
>>> g.c,g.d = g.d,g.c
>>> Foo.a,Foo.b = Foo.b,Foo.a
>>> g_ = pickle.loads(_g)
>>> g_.bar()
(2, 1, 3, 4)
>>> g.bar()
(2, 1, 4, 3)
```

This is even more apparent if you have a list or some other sequence as a class attribute.  So, let's add some list objects to our class.

```
>>> Foo.a = []
>>> Foo.zap = lambda self:self.a
>>> Foo.baz = lambda self,x:self.a.append(x)
>>> 
>>> h = Foo(3,4)
>>> h.baz(0)
>>> h.baz(1)
>>> h.zap()
[0, 1]
>>> _h = pickle.dumps(h)
>>> h.baz(2)
>>> h.baz(3)
>>> h_ = pickle.loads(_h)
>>> h_.zap()
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

This is because the values of the list are actually stored on the class attribute not the instance attribute.  This is one of many examples of this type of behavior.

If you want to preserve the instance "as is" (i.e. not store by reference), then you should pickle with `dill`.  The pickle from `dill` will be bigger, however.

```
>>> import dill
>>> _h = dill.dumps(h)
>>> h.baz(4)
>>> h.baz(5)
>>> h_ = dill.loads(_h)
>>> h_.zap()
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> h.zap()
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```